# How to extract data from an API JSON response?

Tags: json, excel, vba

I am trying to extract data from an API JSON response. Everywhere I read says to use `JsonConverter.ParseJson` and then you can use the data by doing something like `Debug.Print jsonObject("name")`.

I get a 424 error.

```vb
Sub get_request_expansions()
    
    Dim ws          As Worksheet
    Dim jsonObject  As Object
    
    Dim sURL As String
    
    Set request = CreateObject("winhttp.winhttprequest.5.1")
    
    sURL = "https://api.scryfall.com/sets/jmp/"
    
    request.Open "GET", sURL, False
    request.send
    
    '----------
    
    Debug.Print request.responseText
    
    Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(request.responseText)
    Debug.Print jsonObject("name")
    
    '----------
    
    request.abort
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Where/how did you install the json converter?

Comment: Follow the installation instructions in this link: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Comment: Just checked, and your code seems to work here once the JSON converter is installed and you set the appropriate references.

Comment: Oh, I didnt realise that the json convertor needed installing. thought it came standard with excel. I will install it now and try again. thank you.

Comment: Power Query, available in Excel 2010+, has a built-in JSON parser that works well with your link.  However, it requires more programming (which can be automated) to deal with complex, nested JSON's